# How do I make a browser game with unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine

Do I need Unity 3D? Once I make a game with unity 3d how do I 'port' it to the web instead of having it as a download? Can I do it with C#?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install a plugin from Unity called [unity web player](http://unity3d.com/webplayer).

Then export your game to the web format, i think it is the first option in the build menu.

You upload it to your server and just play.